# Batch Script Powershell Snippet on stopping a website

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Don't know much about Powershell, but I have created a bunch of scripts, thanks to Stack Overflow and all people who give examples on how to do something. I have a  snippet and it works for checking a URL and lets me know if its up, down, or don't exist by catching the 100 the batch scripts works fine. Here's a piece of that script:

```
Set CheckUrl=`Powershell.exe -nologo -NoProfile -command "try { (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://exceedtst.infarmbureau.com/Exceed).StatusCode } catch { "100" }"`
```

I use a `for /F` to get the result. Now I'm trying to do the same thing when stopping a website. What I'm currently trying is:

```
Set CheckUrl=`Powershell.exe -nologo -NoProfile -command "try { (Invoke-Command -ComputerName WB-EXCEEDA-DEV -ScriptBlock { Stop-WebAppPool -Name Exceedtst).value } catch { "100" }"`
```

When I run the entire script I get:

> "( was unexpected at this time."

I don't even know if I get the syntax correct even if what I'm trying to do is possible.

Comment: Your second example is syntactically incorrect; as far as your *grouping* operator goes `(..)`. You open it before your `Invoke-Command`, the close it inside your *scriptblock* (`{..}`). Based off the MSDocs, it seems `Stop-WebAppPool` *consumes* the object, and you would need to use `-PassThru` to get the object passed down the pipeline. So: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName WB-EXCEEDA-DEV -ScriptBlock { Stop-WebAppPool -Name Exceedtst }` . Also, couldn't you just stop it from your session?

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes and just try to run the TRY in powershell but it keeps returning a "100" and I know the apppool is started: try { (Invoke-Command -ComputerName WB-EXCEEDA-DEV -ScriptBlock Stop-WebAppPool -Name Exceedtst).value } catch { "100" }

Comment: Whoops, for some reason all I seen on your first comment when I replied was "Your second example is syntactically incorrect; as far as your grouping operator goes (..)" for some reason I didn't see all the rest...thanks, I'll take a look...

Comment: Also each of the commands you've posted are incorrect, because you have not appropriately dealt with the quoting. For instance, your first example should look like this: `powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Try { (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri \"http://exceedtst.infarmbureau.com/Exceed\").StatusCode } Catch { \"100\" }"`.

Comment: Thanks for telling/showing me!